# Underscore's Extend didn't clone my object. What am i doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, node.js, underscore.js

I have the following object:

```
var myCollection = {
    prop1: {
        id:1,
        name:test,
        2dimArray:[
            [1,2,3,4,5],
            [3,4,5,6,7]
        ]
    }
}
```

When i use underscore to clone `prop1` and then change it, like this:

```
var clonedProp = _.extend({}, myCollection.prop1);
clonedProp.2dimArray.splice(1,1);
```

The original `2dimArray` inside `myColloection.prop1` is spliced too, even though i spliced the cloned object.

So the ultimate question as i obviously not using `extend` properly is: How to achieve my goal?

Thanks!

Comment: Its a server side question, I'm using the latest stable Node.js version.

Comment: This happening because extend and copy do shallow copy, you need to write the code that will do deep copy.

Comment: thanks for the answer, shallow copy still holds reference to the original values?

Comment: Where did you clone the object? Your code shows no `_.clone` being called..

Comment: @Mjh `_.extend({}, props)` is the same as  `_.clone`. That is to say `_.clone` **is** `_.extend( {}, props )`

Comment: TBE: I think you should try `var clonedProp = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myCollection.prop1))`. `_.extend` is cloning the reference to the array, not creating a copy of it.

Comment: @PaulOliver it looks like it'll work in this trivial example, maybe not for the real implementation. More details in [this issue](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/issues/162) describing underscore and a `deepCopy` implementation

Comment: @PaulOliver That is what i eventually did and it seems to work. I need it to deep copy not to complex objects.